# Cucumber step definitions are not found after updating to io.cucumber

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

Previously, I was using info.cukes and now I changed to io.cucumber. All the existing steps in features file are not recognized. When I create a new step definition in a new java class, it is still undefined steps in the feature file. However, I can still run all the existing tests successfully. Did anyone have this issue?

Runner class

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json"},
            features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
            glue = {"com.tx.ui.pages", "com.tx.ui.hook"},
            tags = {"@test"})
    public class UiTestRunner {
    }
```

Structure like this

```
├── src
     ├────test
           ├────java
           |      └──com
           |          └──tx
           |              └──ui
           |                  ├────hook
           |                  |      └──cucumberhook.java
           |                  |
           |                  ├────pages
           |                        ├────pageObject.java
           |                        ├────stepDefination.java
           |────resources
                  └── features
                          └── test.feature
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Also, I am using Intellij. Anything related to this?

Comment: The project structure looks ok. Make sure you run `mvn clean` and make sure your IDE hasn't cached anything.

Comment: @M.P. Korstanje I cleared the cache and rebuilded, still the same issue

Comment: Is there a reason you are not setting `test` scope for some dependencies?

Comment: I dunno. Nothing wrong with the code you've shown. You'll have to include your step definitions.